# How to Deal with Special Characters in Communication Frames?

Tags: modbus, serial-communication

I am implementing a very simple communication system based in serial transmission and message frames, small, roughly and loosely adapted from [Modbus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus), with `0x3A` as starting byte, `0x0D 0x0A` sequence as ending bytes.

Most of the action happens when the serial bus detects the `0x3A` byte, and stops until the `0x0D 0x0A` sequence is found.

I would wish a little advice about:

- How should escape "special ending symbols", such as `0x0A` and `0x0D` inside a frame? for example, if one of the data in a frame happens to be equal to `0x0A` (an address?).
- How should I deal with frames with random raw data, i.e. data included in a frame "as is", without any additional conversion, when the special ending byte happens as data?

I noted ASCII represents digits symbols with the `0x30` offset, should I do something like that in order to represent raw data, at the obvious expense of losing bytes? Do this have a possible *real* advantage in here?

Summarizing: Should I stop interpreting the ending bytes as ending bytes and treat all frames as given (predefined or header defined) length?

Answer (score 1):

As an 'escaping scheme' a special escape character (`ESC`) can be inserted before each control character (start-byte, end-byte) that is part of the data. When a reciever receives an `ESC` the next byte is not an control character but part of the data instead. When `ESC` itself is part of the data `ESC` is also inserted before it.

For example with `ESC` `0x10` and data `0x00 0x10 0x3A 0x00 0x0D` the transmitted message should become: `0x3A 0x00 0x10 0x10 0x10 0x3A 0x00 0x10 0x0D 0x0D 0x0A`.